# Questions about algebraic manifold on matrices

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, manifolds

The following snapshot comes from the paper [*Latent Variable Graphical Model Selection Via Convex Optimization*](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~venkatc/cpw_lgm_preprint10.pdf):[image: Latent Variable Graphical Model Selection Via Convex Optimization]

I know little about algebraic geometry so I have several basic questions:

1. How is the dimension of $\mathcal{S}(k)$ and $\mathcal{L}(r)$ calculated? I've found [an explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinantal_variety#Properties) for the latter one, but it's quite complicated. Can you give hints for me?
2. Are some points nonsmooth because they have a smaller dimension?
3. How is the tangent space calculated?
4. Finally, how is the curvature calculated?

Thank you very much for answering. Reference materials are also welcomed.